# Can it even get my generated_keys into the other SQL? - "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

Tags: java, mysql, sql

It's like the id that I get back at addShedId and throw it into a place where it should update. Then it fails by typing "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

When it's going to "*create shed*", it may be well done but as soon as it has to add generated_keys to **UPDATE_SHEDID_SQL**. then it will come up with that mistake.

```
pstm = connection.prepareStatement(CREATE_SHED_SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            pstm.setInt(1, shedLength);
            pstm.setInt(2, shedWidth);
            //pstm.addBatch();

            pstm.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet rs = pstm.getGeneratedKeys();
            rs.next();

            int addShedId = rs.getInt(1);
            PreparedStatement pstm2 = connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE_SHEDID_SQL);
            pstm2.setInt(1, addShedId);
            pstm2.setInt(2, id);
            pstm2.executeUpdate();
```

It all works well if I drive them individually, just simply show.

SQL:

```
CREATE_SHED_SQL = "INSERT INTO Sheds(length, width) VALUES(?,?)"

UPDATE_SHEDID_SQL = "UPDATE Carportrequests SET shedId = ? WHERE id = ?"
```

Comment: Sorry to say we can't help you unless you show us the actual SQL represented by your CREATE_SHED_SQL and UPDATE_SHEDID_SQL symbols.

Comment: i have update :)

Comment: I think MySQL needs to close the ResultSet from the first statement, before executing the second statement. Try adding `rs.close()` right after you retrieve the `addShedId` value.

Comment: Thanks for help @TheImpaler